# ¿Por qué este error en un bucle 'while'?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter

Disponemos de este DataFrame,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def crear_df_cotiz(num_days):
    np.random.seed(100)
    dates = pd.date_range('20160104', periods=1000, freq='D')
    datos1 = pd.DataFrame(dates ,columns=['Date'])
    datos2 = pd.DataFrame((np.random.randn(num_days) + np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=0.2, size=num_days)) ,columns=['High'])
    datos3 = pd.DataFrame((np.random.randn(num_days) + np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=0.2, size=num_days)) ,columns=['Low'])
    datos4 = pd.DataFrame((np.random.randn(num_days) + np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=0.2, size=num_days)), columns=['Close'])
    datos5 = pd.DataFrame((np.random.randn(num_days) + np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=0.2, size=num_days)) ,columns=['Volume'])

    df_cotizaciones = pd.concat([datos1,datos2,datos3,datos4, datos5],axis=1)
    df_cotizaciones['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_cotizaciones['Date'], format='%Y%m%d')
    df_cotizaciones.set_index("Date", inplace = True)
    return df_cotizaciones

num_days = 1000 
df_cotizaciones  = crear_df_cotiz(num_days)
df_cotizaciones[:3]
```

Con sus datos, quiero calcular el siguiente índice.

```
 def calcular_TR(df, n):

        i = 0
        TR_l = [0]
        while i < df.index[-1]:
            TR = max(df.loc[i + 1, 'High'], df.loc[i, 'Close']) - min(df.loc[i + 1, 'Low'], df.loc[i, 'Close'])
            TR_l.append(TR)
            i = i + 1
        TR_s = pd.Series(TR_l)
        ATR = pd.Series(TR_s.ewm(span=n, min_periods=n).mean(), name='ATR_' + str(n))
        df = df.join(ATR)
        
        # Plot 
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        atr.plot(ax=ax, lw = 1.5)
        data[name].plot(ax=ax, secondary_y=True, alpha=0.3, lw=1.5)
        plt.show()
                
        return df

df_ATR =  calcular_TR(df_cotizaciones, 14)
```

Me devuelve

---

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_8590/3230883361.py in 
19        return df
20
---> 21 df_ATR =  calcular_TR(df_cotizaciones, 14)

/tmp/ipykernel_8590/3230883361.py in calcular_TR(df, n)
3        i = 0
4        TR_l = [0]
----> 5        while i < df.index[-1]:
6            TR = max(df.loc[i + 1, 'High'], df.loc[i, 'Close']) - min(df.loc[i + 1, 'Low'], df.loc[i, 'Close'])
7            TR_l.append(TR)

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'Timestamp'

Las caracteristicas del DataFrame son:

```
df_cotizaciones.info()
```

[image: características de df]

No entiendo el error devuelto. Agradeceré ayuda.

Comment: `df.index[-1]` es un `DatetimeIndex`, mientras que `i` es un entero. ¿Cual es la intención al comparar `i < df.index[-1]` ?

Comment: Gracias Candid. iterar sobre todos los registros del DataFrame. Tendré que pensar en otra forma de hacerlo.

Comment: Se me olvidó resetear el índice. Me falla alguna neurona

Comment: Tambien se podría sustituir por: while i < len(df) -1: